# How to test PHP Socket Programming in localhost + ubuntu

Tags: php, sockets

I have two files:

**client.php**

```
<?php
$host    = "127.0.0.1";
$port    = 25003;
$message = "Hello Server";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

and **server.php**

```
<?php
$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 25003;
set_time_limit(0);
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

I am running http://www.domain.com/php-socket/client.php from browser. But I don't know how to run server.php on server side using terminal. My php-socket root directory is `/var/www/php-socket/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please open terminal and type bellow command

> **cd /var/www/php-socket**
>
> **php server.php**